# Combinatorics Math Competition Question: Solve for given probability sum

Tags: combinatorics

> Q: A fair 6-faced die is thrown 3 times.Find the probability that the sum of numbers obtained is greater than 5

This was a question that appeared in the 2018 Thailand International Mathematics Olympiad. I am currently preparing for the TIMO heats in my country...

I have some knowledge on counting(permutation and combinations) and also basic probability

Comment: Please add more details about where exactly you are stuck. As a bare minimum, please tell us the techniques your teacher has taught you to solve similar questions so we can phrase answers at the right level of knowledge

Comment: Couldn't have said it better.

Answer (score 2):

Total there are $6^3=216$ ways to roll the die (including duplicates), and the ways to have sum $\leq 5$ is

$(1, 1, 1)$ 1 way

$(1, 1, 2)$ 3 ways

$(1, 1, 3)$ 3 ways

$(1, 2, 2)$ 3 ways

Hence probability is $\frac{216-1-3-3-3}{216} = \frac{103}{108}$